# Calculating a conditional mean and store it in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate a conditional mean for values that exceed a certain threshold.

For example by looking at the cars dataset, I want to calculate the mean hp for cars with more than 100 hp. Furthermore, I want to store this value within a datastream.

I tried the following Code (`PROPTV` is the dataset and `DDM, g=0` is the variable for which I need the mean of values>0):

```
PROPTV %>% 
  group_by(`DDM, g=0`>0) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(`DDM, g=0`))
```

I get the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  `\`DDM, g=0\` > 0`  mean
  <lgl>              <dbl>
1 FALSE              0    
2 TRUE               0.709
```

The 0.709 should be correct but I have no idea how to store this value without using any help dataframe.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your question is confusing me. What do you mean by "without using any help data frame"? What's wrong with the output you have here? Are you looking to extract just the value 0.709? If so, add `%>% filter(\`DDM, g=0\`) %>% pull(mean)` to your code after `summarise()`.

Comment: Hello Phil. Thanks for your reply! I meant without using a second data frame to store the value. So what I want to avoid is something like this: helpvalue <- PROPTV %>% 
  group_by(`DDM, g=0`>0) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(`DDM, g=0`)) and then using DESK[1,1] <- helpvalue[2,2] (DESK is the data frame where I want to store the value) For some reason your code did not work either.

Comment: With your code I get two values ([1] 0.7088506        NA) and `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 32, 1, value = c(0.708850627178554,  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1. Is there any possibility to just pull the mean for values>0 so that I get only one row as a outcome?

Comment: It would be easier to help with a reproducible example, but offhand you can always use one of the `*_join` functions (like `left_join()`) to merge data frames back together.